# Author initials for article in German newspapers

Tags: usage, abbreviation

In the Frankfurter Allgemeine Zeitung, I see abbreviations like

> **Sarkozy gibt Kandidatur für UMP-Vorsitz bekannt**
>
> mic. PARIS, 19. September. Der frühere französische Präsident Nicolas Sarkozy ...

I assume that "mic." are the initials of the author of this article. Is that true? (I've never seen this in English-based newspapers before.)

If so, how can I find out the full name of the author? (The article is not continued on other pages.)

Another example:

> **Schotten stimmen gegen Unabhängigkeit**
>
> Cameron ruft zur Geschlossenheit auf und verspricht größere Autonomie / Erleichterung in Brüssel
>
> job./theu./now. EDINBURGH/LONDON/BRÜSSEL, 19. September. In Schottland haben 55 Prozent der Stimmberechtigten gegen die Abspaltung ...

Comment: Are we talking about in the print version of the paper, or online? I don't see the same abbreviations in online articles, but rather a full author's name.

Comment: @Milchgesicht I'm talking about the print version of the paper, and also not all articles. Some articles do have the full name of the author.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a `Kürzel` and represent the author or the source of the article.

This `Kürzel` may be the initials, but it may be another abbreviation. 
In the print version is sometimes a list nearby the '[Impressum](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impressum)'.

You can check some examples of Kürzel on the website of the [FAZ](http://fazarchiv.faz.net/info/Autoren), for Baden-Württemberg

There are special Kürzel:

- `red` is normally not a person but the [Redaktion](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redaktion).
- dpa is the [Deutsche Presse-Agentur](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Presse-Agentur)
- epd is the [Evangelischer Pressedienst](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evangelischer_Pressedienst)
- ddp was the [Deutscher Depeschendienst](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutscher_Depeschendienst)
- You can find more News agency at wikipedia: [Nachrichten- und Presseagentur](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nachrichten-_und_Presseagentur)

Answer (score 4):

You are right, it’s the author, Michaela Wiegel in this case. The abbrevation is displayed prominently on [her author profile](http://www.faz.net/redaktion/michaela-wiegel-11104455.html).

[Here](http://www.faz.net/redaktion/) is a list of FAZ authors – or just google for `"FAZ" + [shortname]`.

Comment: There's even a search engine for the "Kürzel" (logogram). Here's a search for [job.](http://www.faz.net/redaktion/?activeInputElement=queryKurzl&x=0&y=0&author=Name&queryK=job.&offset=&sort=abc&resultsPerPage=20) (the dot must be typed).